# change of style for inner components when MenuItem is selected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I used createMuiTheme and put my theme for pallette -> action -> selected and it works for i.e. when MenuItem is selected. But now I would like to change the color of inner components of MenuItem i.e ListItemIcon and  ListItemText when selected theme is applied to MenuItem? Is it possible to do it with createMuitTheme as well and how?

version: Material-ui 1.0.0-beta.34

Answer (score 0):

Colors may be defined as:

```
theme.palette.primary.main
theme.palette.secondary.main
theme.palette.error.main
```

Also for active elements:

```
theme.palette.action.active
```

Secondary text may be specified also:

```
theme.palette.text.secondary
```